# mongoDB: $project find array-index by value (How can i use filter() in a $project-statment ?)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with data like this:

```
 {
    _id: 9999,
    sales : [
          {date: "mo", sum: 2},
          {date: "we", sum: 5},
    ]
 },
 {
    _id: 2323,
    sales : [
          {date: "mo", sum: 10},
          {date: "we", sum: 23},
    ]
 }
```

I need the "sum"-field in the sales-array for each document in the collection (but only for one given date-string). I try this:

```
db.foo.aggregate(
{ $project : {
  sales_day: "$sales.filter(function(item) { return item.date = "we" });",
 }
})
```

We he always set a empty array if a add any filter-function. Even it the filter-function return true all the time.

I need something like the Array.prototype.filter-Function inside the mongodb.

If i had this:

```
var tofind = "do";
sales = sales.filter(function(item) {
   return item.date = tofind;
});

sales_day = sales.sum;
```

The string i search for in the date-field have to be dynamically because it can change with every query. I also cannot use some group-syntax because there is a very complex query - this is only on part but this part I don't get to work.

In the further aggregation-steps i needed this data in pipeline (for date="mo" as a example)

```
{
    _id: 9999,
    sales_day: 2
 },
 {
    _id: 2323,
    sales_day: 5
 }
```

Someone have an idea?

ATTENTION: After that i do more steps in the pipeline - but i need the field "sales_day" for further group/sort.

Comment: You need to clearly state your objective in your question if you want someone to provide the answer you expect. Don't argue with people that "they don't understand". It is never their fault, it is yours. Write your question with a clear explanation. Then you will get accurate answers. At least one anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call JavaScript functions in your pipeline and you perform any `aggregate` filtering using `$match`, not `$project`.

```javascript
var toFind = 'we';
db.foo.aggregate([
    // Filter to just the docs that contain at least one of the sales elements
    {$match: {'sales.date': toFind}},
    // Duplicate each doc, once per sales element.
    {$unwind: '$sales'},
    // Filter to just the docs with the sales element we need
    {$match: {'sales.date': toFind}},
    // Reshape the docs to have a sales_day field
    {$project: {sales_day: '$sales.sum'}}
])
```

Output:

```javascript
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 9999,
            "sales_day" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2323,
            "sales_day" : 23
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I don't need the documents back. I need a new field in the pipeline because next i do different groups/$sum/sort with this field.

Comment: @user3351722 Do you mean that you need both the original `sales` array field and a new `sales_day` field?  Could you edit your question to include what output you're looking for with those example docs?

Comment: @user3351722 You can reshape the documents like that with a `$project`.  See updated answer.

Comment: @JohhnyHK: Amazing - Thank you that seems to be working!!!! I do a few tests and come back than.